# R: change font for hist and barplot

Tags: r, fonts

I tried to change the font of my hist and barplot (with R), but I can not succeed... I tried the extrafont package but I can not find how to change it...

How can I simply change all of the fonts for all of my graph (hist and barcharts) ? I only have axis labels and of course the numbers on the axis.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, set it globally like this

```
windowsFonts(times = windowsFont("Times New Roman")) 
par(family = "times", font = 2, font.lab = 2, font.axis = 2)
barplot(1, names.arg = 1, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
hist(rnorm(1:100))
```

or path it to the plotting function itself like this

```
barplot(1, names.arg = 1, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", family = "serif", font = 2, font.lab = 2, font.axis = 2)
```

Have a look at the help `?par` for further info on the parameters like font.lab.

Comment: Thanks @LukeA. with "par(family = "times", font = 2, font.lab = 2, font.axis = 2)", it will be working for all of the graphs that are produced with this script? I am looking for using Gill sans MT. I will try this.

Comment: I have this error when I add your script: "Warning message:
In title(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) :
  font family not found in Windows font database"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did this:  "
windowsFonts(Gill = windowsFont("Gill Sans MT")) 
par(family = "Gill" , font = 1, font.lab = 1, font.axis = 1)" to apply it to all of my graphs with Gill Sans MT. But for some of the graphes, the font is bigger...

Comment: @nif Use `cex` and its relatives (like with `font`) to specify the font size (look at `?par`).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy for people to point to the `par` help page. But at least for R version 3.5.2 the solution is not on that page!

In the `barplot` the x-axis is technically not an axis since it uses the names of the supplied vector. So, you need to set `cex.names = 0.5` for smaller text. Alternatively, you can use a larger value for larger text.

```
a <- c(1:3)
names(a) <- c(1:3)
barplot(a, cex.names = 2)
```

Good luck!

[image]